# Does SQLite further optimise range-limited JOIN ... WHERE column > N?

Tags: sqlite

```sql
CREATE TABLE readings 
(
    t INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    payload TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE device_readings 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    t INTEGER,
    device_payload TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(t) REFERENCES readings(t)
);

CREATE INDEX idx_device_readings_t ON device_readings(t);
```

```sql
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT readings.t, payload, device_payload
FROM device_readings
 JOIN readings ON device_readings.t = readings.t
WHERE readings.t > 10000;
```

```
QUERY PLAN
|--SEARCH device_readings USING INDEX idx_device_readings_t (t>?)
`--SEARCH readings USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
```

Looks like for `device_readings` SQLite will first binary-search the record on 10000 boundary and then simply start iterating over index towards increasing values.

Does SQLite bother to do a similar trick on the `readings` side? It could optimize lookups by first finding the 10000 boundary, and then looking up by binary-searching only within (10000-record, max_record).

UPD: Postgres does range-limit binary search on both sides of join, but only if the range condition is duplicated: readings.t > 10000 AND device_readings.t > 10000.

Is there any way to force SQLite to do that?

Comment: It's not exactly clear why sqlite should even do that: Having read a record - in fact, just the index, the record being there is implied by the index - in `device_readings`, sqlite has the primary key value for `readings.t`. This value is unique, there is no point in using an already implied condition that we know to be true. Am I missing something you'd expect?